# Lost minibuffer message in emacs when disable/enable modes

Tags: emacs

I recently updated some packages for my emacs 24.3 under Windows, and I found strangely that the mode change messages used to be shown in minibuffer is gone, e.g., before update, when i enable or disable any minor mode, there is a message showing up in the minibuffer saying: xxx-mode is disabled. but now, this message is gone, although i can still check if the mode is disabled or enabled in the mode line. But it not as obvious by displaying a message in minibuffer.

anyone knows what can be the cause?
thanks

Comment: Pretty vague description: some modes (which?), some packages (which? updated to what versions?). If you are more specific then people might be able to help you more. If you know such a package & mode, then you can also look at its code to see whether it calls `message` etc. If it uses `define-minor-mode` then a msg should be shown.  You can find (most) messages logged in buffer `*Messages*`.

Comment: well, actually any mode, minor or major, when i disable/enable it, there is no message showing up in minibuffer, i also checked the *Messages* buffer, no message about mode change there either. I believe there is certain variable of vanilla Emacs for that, which is not related to the packages that i update.

Comment: No such variable that I know of. To inhibit logging messages one can bind `message-log-max` to nil, but even that does not prevent displaying messages in the echo area.

Answer (score 0):

seems the problem only happens on  x64 version Emacs 24.3, windows, switch to 32bit version and everything is ok now